# using combobox on a form to filter the report - MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to filter the report based on a value in combo box on a form.

Private Sub OpenReport_Click()
DoCmd.OpenReport "Warehouse Stock Summary", acViewReport, "[ProductName] =" & Me.Combo202

End Sub

Where,

Warehouse Stock Summary is the name of the report,
Product Name is the column in the report based on whcih I want to filter the report.
Combo202 contains the distinct values for ProductName

Can anyone please help, where I am going wrong? The code above is not filtering the report. It will just give the results for all values.

Thanks,

Rohan

Answer (score 0):

Try with quotes around the text value:

```vb
Private Sub OpenReport_Click() 

    DoCmd.OpenReport "Warehouse Stock Summary", acViewReport, "[ProductName] = '" & Me!Combo202 & "'"

End Sub
```

Also, rename Combo202 to something meaningful.